# What's a word or phrase that means 'take advantage of someone's psychological weaknesses'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for something that's catchy and succinct. 'Exploit' is a good word for 'take advantage of' but it doesn't take into account someone's psychological weaknesses.

example sentences:

> "By taking advantage of her substance abuse in order to get sex, he was _________ her."

or

> "She took advantage of his bad memory by repeatedly getting him to wash the dishes more often than not. She was _________ him."

Comment: Pull a fast one, cash in on,  capitalize.

Comment: Would "manipulate" do the trick ?

Comment: Will the down-voters show some courtesy!

Comment: I don't think there's anything in 'manipulate' that is connotative of the victim's psychological weaknesses. It's possible to use it in that sense but you would have to do so explicitly.

Comment: For the first one you could say *figuratively and literally screwing her*. Since screw = Slang. to cheat or take advantage of(someone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**gaslight**

.

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/gaslight)

> verb: Manipulate (someone) by psychological means into questioning their own sanity:

.

[dictionary.com definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gaslight)

> 4. to cause (a person) to doubt his or her sanity through the use of psychological manipulation:

.

I think that's the closest I'm gonna get to what I want..

Answer (score 2):

This can be known as ***playing head games***

Also *playing **mind games***

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/head%20game) says

> Definition of **head game**
>   : MIND GAME

and of   [*mind games*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mind%2Bgame):

> : a psychological tactic used to manipulate or intimidate —usually used in plural *< played mind games with his opponent >*

Answer (score 2):

Try *play to a weakness*. Here's part of a [review](http://blogs.usyd.edu.au/theoryandpractice/2015/08/) of a book about Simón Bolívar, who led the campaigns in the 1820s to oust the Spanish from their South American colonies:

> Though the author describes many battles, it is all too much like a
>   game. As far as I could tell Bolívar’s main tactic was to attack
>   head-on. There is little indication he studied the terrain, disposed
>   his forces according to it, tried to *understand his opponents’ mind
>   and **play to a weakness***, as did Robert Lee.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your second example to one, neater, sentence, by using "milking", which is a near-perfect synonym for "taking advantage". Also, I would use "absent-mindedness" instead of "bad memory". Also "repeatedly" and "more often than not" are, well, repetitive. Now, in a cleaned-up form, may be "taking advantage" doesn't sound so bad. Which is better?

"She was milking his absent-mindedness by repeatedly getting him to wash the dishes."

"She was taking advantage" of his absent-mindedness by repeatedly getting him to wash the dishes."

Answer (score 0):

To ***[subjugate](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/subjugate)*** has the connotation that you are referring to:

> - to treat yourself, your wishes, or your beliefs as being less important than other people or their wishes or beliefs:
>
>   - *She subjugated herself to her mother's needs.*
>   - *Reporters must subjugate personal political convictions to their professional commitment to balance.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

Exploit seems like the proper word to me.

Comment: This could be a good answer if you include a definition for the word (and a citation for the definition).